# Azure container sync periodically

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-logic-apps, azcopy, file-storage

I have a scenario where i am storing payload from 2 subscriber (Service bus topics) into 2 different storage/container. Storing mechanism are different in these case.
Now i have to run a sync every 30 minutes  which will compare the files created target and Source,
if anything is missing in the target it should be able to copy that file from source to target.

I am looking at AZCopy sync, but that is a local application . There are logic app and Function app option as well.

Kindly share what is the best solution to this problem

Comment: My instinct is to suggest Azure Data Factory. You should be able to use Get Metadata to list the contents of each and discover the missing items. Can you explain what you mean by "Storing mechanism are different in these case"?

Comment: Thank for the quick response.

Comment: Payloads are currently stored via mulesoft doing SFTP in our container. Now i am able to store them directly from service bus, but the reason sync is needed because there has been scenarios where we have lost data due to service not available at mulesoft end. Hence sync comes into the picture

Comment: OK - but you are asking how to sync two Storage Containers, right? So the originator isn't really part of the problem?

Comment: yeah, we are expecting some data loss at at on of the target which we want to sync internally. Not the right scenario but this is how it is

Comment: One more question: if you have container A and container B - is one of them always "right", or do you need to cross-sync between the two?

Comment: B is always right, and need to sync into A only

Answer (score 1):

This method is a little on the brute force side, but should work. Here is the top level pipeline diagram:

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. Get Metadata for the "Needs sync" folder (FolderA). Be sure to check add the "Child items" argument:

[image]

2. ForEach over the FolderA child items to extract the file names and append them to an array variable:

[image]

[image]

This makes it easier to work with the names later.

3. Get Metadata for the "Always right" folder (FolderB). Same process as above, but over the FolderB location.
4. ForEach over FolderB's child items.

[image]

5. Inside the ForEach, add an If Condition to test whether or not the FolderB item exists in the FolderA list.

[image]

[image]

6. If the FolderB item is not in the FolderA list, append it to a Missing_Items array variable.

[image]

From here, it's a matter of looping over the Missing Items array and handling it however you prefer [probably with a Copy activity].